# Change the width of the search bar

Tags: magento2

I am a newbie and I am just getting started with all this so I apologize for my lack of education about this in advance.  I am trying to change the size of the search bar on Magento 2.  I have made a child theme from the parent magento and I just cant seem to change the width of the search bar.  I did search the similar articles but I had no luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Add some CSS to Change Width of Search Bar No Need to Overwrite any File.

Add This CSS code to your .css file

```
.page-wrapper .block.block-search {
    width: 100%;
}
```

For CSS File Path

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/Magento_Theme/web/css/cssFileName.css
```

OR

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/web/css/cssFileName.css
```

***NOTE:- Magento has multiple Theme for Different Stores so Kindly Check which Theme are Currently used. to check follow this step.***

1) In Admin, go to **CONTENT > Design > Configuration**. A Design Configuration page opens. It contains a grid with the available configuration scopes.

2) In the configuration record corresponding to your store view, click **Edit**. The page with design configuration for the selected scope opens.

3) On the **Default Theme tab**, in the **Applied Theme** drop-down, select your newly created theme.

4) Click Save *Configuration*

5) If caching is enabled, **clear the cache.** Click **System > Cache Management**.Clear the invalid cache types.

6) To see your changes applied, **reload** the storefront pages.

Reference Link:- [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

You have to just copy core file into your child theme and customize as per your need,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{childthemme}/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

and add in your css file.

```
.header.content .block.block-search {width: 300px;}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some simple CSS.

```
/* Size of the search box */
.form-search input.input-text {
    width: 250px; /* Your desired width */
}
```

Hope it helps..